# Is there a way to use bootstrap tabs without using a unique identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

I would like to be able to use bootstrap tabs but without using a unique selector.

I cannot guarantee that the selector is the only one in the dom.

I have many sub templates which are either included in the page as it is rendered or can be loaded inside a modal via ajax.

I do use id's but never in the templates i might use within a modal, some modals are preloaded after the page load event.

```
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a data-target=".pane1" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">pane 1</a></li>
        <li><a data-target=".pane2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">pane 2</a></li>
      </ul>     
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane pane1">pane 1</div>
        <div class="tab-pane pane2">pane 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have tried an `onclick` event on the anchor tag with just jquery which is less than ideal, but cannot get it to work with the `.tab('show')`

```
onclick="$(this).closest('.panel')
   .find('.tab-pane').hide();$(this).closest('.panel').find('.pane1').show();"
```

Comment: Wait, you can have exclusive classes but not ids?

Comment: Also, why can't you guarantee unique ids? Maybe giving more information about that will allow us to help you find a solution without writing huge jquery selectors

Comment: That is a rather OTT jQuery selector chain. have a look at https://api.jquery.com/end/

Comment: why are you using `onclick` when it already works using your markup and no ID's? http://plnkr.co/edit/nnsXInx3Hyuti3qjNPuR?p=preview

Comment: it wont work if i have duplicate selectors. ill make an edit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is possible...for this HTML:

```
 <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#">pane 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">pane 2</a></li>
      </ul>     
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane">pane 1</div>
        <div class="tab-pane">pane 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This Javascript:

```
$('.panel .nav-tabs').on('click', 'a', function(e){
  var tab  = $(this).parent(),
      tabIndex = tab.index(),
      tabPanel = $(this).closest('.panel'),
      tabPane = tabPanel.find('.tab-pane').eq(tabIndex);
  tabPanel.find('.active').removeClass('active');
  tab.addClass('active');
  tabPane.addClass('active');
});
```

See [**this functioning bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/dXPmn2lB5B)

**Note** Take note that I removed all `data` attributes from the anchors to prevent bootstraps auto wireup to them**

Comment: Brilliant thank you.  it seems to work perfectly. i though the answer was going to be simpler than that. great job.

Answer (score -2):

This solution uses role attributes to control functionality rather than class names, all role are valid ARIA values. http://accessibility.athena-ict.com/aria/examples/tabpanel2.shtml. The solution works when nesting "tabpanels".

```
   <div role="tabpanel">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation"><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel">1</div>
        <div role="tabpanel">2</div>
        <div role="tabpanel">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div role="tabpanel">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation"><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel">1</div>
        <div role="tabpanel">2</div>
        <div role="tabpanel">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

javascript

I modified bootstrap tabs "show" method to include this code these lines.

```
var $context = $this.closest('[role="tabpanel"]');
if($context.length && $target.length != 1){

    if($target.length > 1){
        $target = $context.find('[role="tabpanel"] ').eq($this.parent().index());
    } else {
        $target = $context.find(selector).length ? $context.find(selector) : $target;
    }
}
```

Full method.

```
 $.fn.tab.Constructor.prototype.show=function(){var t=this.element,e=t.closest("ul:not(.dropdown-menu)"),a=t.data("target");if(a||(a=t.attr("href"),a=a&&a.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/,"")),!t.parent("li").hasClass("active")){var r=e.find(".active:last a"),n=$.Event("hide.bs.tab",{relatedTarget:t[0]}),i=$.Event("show.bs.tab",{relatedTarget:r[0]});if(r.trigger(n),t.trigger(i),!i.isDefaultPrevented()&&!n.isDefaultPrevented()){var l=$(a),s=t.closest('[role="tabpanel"]');s.length&&1!=l.length&&(l=l.length>1?s.find('.tab-pane, [role="tabpanel"] ').eq(t.parent().index()):s.find(a).length?s.find(a):l),this.activate(t.closest("li"),e),this.activate(l,l.parent(),function(){r.trigger({type:"hidden.bs.tab",relatedTarget:t[0]}),t.trigger({type:"shown.bs.tab",relatedTarget:r[0]})})}}};
```